# Configure settings.xml for Openshift 3.10 S2I Maven Builds

Tags: openshift

I would like to to customize settings.xml for s2i maven builds in Openshift 3.10. While this is easily done in version 3.11 using config maps:

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#using-secrets-during-build

I did not found any solution for 3.10. Is there a workaround / solution for this?

thank you!

Comment: Have you confirmed this isn't working for you in 3.10? ConfigMaps have been around for awhile, so I would suspect the solution would still work in 3.10. What have you tried for 3.10 and what error messages are you seeing?

Comment: basically there is no flag for this when I create a build, see: --build-config-map "settings-mvn". 
But right I will try to do just by modifying the build object.

Comment: You _should_ be able to just add another command and do `oc set volume bc/<build> --configmap-name=''` with the other settings filled in for where to mount, etc...but that should at least be an alternative to manually modifying the build object (unless `oc set volume` is a 3.11 command, which would be unfortunate).

Comment: I tried this `oc volume bc/my-buildonfig-name --add -t=configmap --configmap-name=settings-mvn  --mount-path=.m2`
But I received:
`error: the buildconfigs my-buildonfig-name is not a pod or does not have a pod template`

Comment: Yeah, my apologies...it looks like `oc set volume` works on the pod spec, so I guess it won't work on a build config. Looking again at the documentation, I suspect that the `configMaps` section of the definition may not actually be added to the API until 3.11, which is unfortunate. As a workaround, you should be able to just store the `settings.xml` as a secret as opposed to a configmap, and have it work the same as a configmap. I don't have a 3.10 cluster available to test, so you'll have to let me know if this works for you.

Comment: At the end it worked by using secrets in the following way:
`oc create secret generic secret-mvn-settings --from-file=settings.xml=/home/mystuff/settings.xml`

`oc new-build redhat-openjdk18-openshift:1.4~https://mygitrepoprovider.com/myrepo.git --build-secret "secret-mvn-settings:/opt/rh/rh-maven35/root/usr/share/maven/conf"`

Here I'm overriding the global maven settings ( can been seen adding -X to maven command). It did not work with  `"secret-mvn-settings:.m2"` from the docs of 3.11. 

So thank you very much for help. If you formulate this as an answer I will accept.

Comment: To give it a more little more context for readers: the user and not the global maven settings.xml is initialized on the start of the build. I was not oble to override this - neither using a new build image or by setting new settings.xml with MAVEN_ARGS. Probably it would work to specify a global setting, but this way works too.

Comment: I was just working up an answer to post here, and came across these docs: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_middleware_for_openshift/3/html-single/red_hat_java_s2i_for_openshift/index#providing_custom_maven_settings. Does placing the settings.xml file in your git repo work for you? Or even where you mount the secret? It might be more reliable, especially in future versions in case that path ever changes

Comment: This actually worsk too! Although because of securty we will consider which one solution to use. 
But anyways thank you for help!

Comment: @WillGordon it would be great if you could make a summary of these 2 approaches and put it in an short answer. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3.11, you can create a ConfigMap for your `settings.xml` file

```
$ oc create configmap settings-mvn --from-file=settings.xml=<path/to/settings.xml>
```

And use that to override it in your build. ([Source](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#using-secrets-during-build))

```
source:
  git:
    uri: https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart.git
  contextDir: helloworld
  configMaps:
    - configMap:
        name: settings-mvn
```

---

As you point out, 3.10, there is no support for ConfigMaps in BuildConfigs, however, you can create a secret with the same content

```
$ oc create secret generic settings-mvn --from-file=settings.xml=<path/to/settings.xml>
```

And use that to override it in your build. ([Source](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#using-secrets-during-build))

```
source:
  git:
    uri: https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart.git
  contextDir: helloworld
  secrets:
    - secret:
        name: settings-mvn
```

---

Alternatively, you can also include the `settings.xml` file in your git repo in order to override the default `settings.xml`. Simply placing your file at `source_dir/configuration/settings.xml` should be sufficient. ([Source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_middleware_for_openshift/3/html-single/red_hat_java_s2i_for_openshift/index#providing_custom_maven_settings))