# custom maven settings.xml for openshift build

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, configmap

### I'm using openshift 4, and building image using base image ubi8/openjdk-8 image.
I wan't to use my custom maven settings.xml file.
I see that openshift uses file located here

```
/tmp/artifacts/configuration/settings.xml
```

So how can I tell openshift to read my custom settings.xml file, and not that in configuration folder.

Thanks in advance

I have tried to build configMap and put that custom setting.xml to it, apply that custom map to buildConfi [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691270/configure-settings-xml-for-openshift-3-10-s2i-maven-builds) but it doesn't work.
My configMap is :

`kind: ConfigMap apiVersion: v1 metadata: name: settings-mvn2 namespace: int-dev uid: 2d3b1aad-6d7a-4e69-9848-3c48470ec7b3 resourceVersion: '1465541561' creationTimestamp: '2023-12-08T09:16:34Z' managedFields: - manager: kubectl-create operation: Update apiVersion: v1 time: '2023-12-08T09:16:34Z' fieldsType: FieldsV1 fieldsV1: 'f:data': .: {} 'f:settings.xml': {} data: settings.xml: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<settings xmlns=\"http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\r\n  xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.2.0.xsd\">\r\n     <mirrors>\r\n          <mirror>\r\n               <id>maven-default-http-blocker</id>\r\n               <mirrorOf>dummy</mirrorOf>\r\n               <name>Dummy mirror to override default blocking mirror that blocks http</name>\r\n               <url>http://0.0.0.0/</url>\r\n         </mirror>\r\n    </mirrors>\r\n</settings>"`

Comment: `mvn -s /home/goose/mvn-tmp-settings.xml` is what I use. That I alias to `mvnt`

Comment: Thanks for advice, but where should I enter that command. Do I create some new configMap or something like that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would depend on how you invoke mvn. And that I don't know

Comment: The maven build is called when assembly script during S2I build, and this is from log `INFO Running 'mvn -e -Popenshift -DskipTests -Dcom.redhat.xpaas.repo.redhatga -Dfabric8.skip=true -Djkube.skip=true --batch-mode -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -s /tmp/artifacts/configuration/settings.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=/tmp/artifacts/m2 package'`  So I would like to change that /tmp/artifacts/configuration/settings.xml to lool to my custom maven setting.xml